# Is there a way to show alt="text" as a mouseover tooltip in firefox like IE does automatically?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, seo, accessibility

I don't want to repeat alt text in title again?  is this possible with any javascript , jquery, css solution? or any solution which can disable to show alt=text and enable title=texr and as a tooltip?

Comment: This is a bug of the Internet Explorer to show the alternative text as a tooltip. (Microsoft may call this a feature but the alternative text is only meant to be shown when the image cannot be displayed.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`alt` text is for an **alternative** representation of an image.  `title` text is for tooltips.

IE's behavior is **incorrect** in this regard, and Firefox will never implement it.  (The bug in the Bugzilla database is [#25537](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25537), which is VERIFIED WONTFIX.)

Not only that, but even [Microsoft has admitted that their behavior is incorrect](https://web.archive.org/web/20090624020206/http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=334225), and **IE 8 doesn't show `alt` text as tooltips anymore**!.

So don't rely on `alt` text being displayed as a tooltip.  Use `title` instead.

Comment: i know but i don't want to repeat alt text as a title text again and want to show tooltip on mouse over in both browser.

Comment: @Jitendra: You shouldn't be repeating the `alt` text for the `title` anyway.  The `alt` text should be what you want users to see if they **can't** see the image, while `title` should be for tooltips.  If you have both `alt` and `title` defined in your HTML, IE will use `title` for the tooltip.  So if you want only one element for all modern browsers, use `title`, not `alt`!

Answer (score 36):

The correct way to do this is to use the **title** attribute.

e.g.

```
<div title="This is your tooltip">...content...</div>
```

The "alt" attribute is only designed to provide "alternative" text when an image element is used (but not available to the user... e.g. blind users, or users with text-based browsers etc.)

Comment: did u just said that blind users can't see the image but they can see the specified Alt text? :o

Comment: @Rakesh Juyal: Blind users will have screen reader software.  Screen readers can read **text**, but not images.

Comment: @Daniel: gr8 i never knew it thanx +1

Answer (score 6):

Like scunliffe says, the right way to do this is in the `title` attribute. Its better to comply to the standard than rely on IE's non-standard behavior. Keep in mind the title attribute is for tooltips for users that can see the image, alt text is for users who can't (although they can see the title as well). If this really bugs you, you can just use javascript to set the title attributes to the alt attributes for all your images, giving you a cross browser effect. :D

Something like this:

```
 var images=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
 for (var item in images) {
     item.title = item.alt;
 }
```

OR (W3 DOM style)

```
 for (var item in images) {
     item.setAttribute("title", item.getAttribute("alt") );
 }
```

OR (jQuery)

```
 $("img").each( function() { this.attr("title", this.attr("alt") ); }
```

(haven't tested any of these yet, so slight modification may be needed)

Comment: Reusing `alt` text for the `title` attribute is a bad idea for accessibility.  There is virtually no case where the same text is appropriate for both.

Comment: This was one of my first points to state when writing this answer, but I couldn't think of a good example. Could you provide one? :D

Comment: Jitendra post some code in the question and we'll do our best to help. :D

Answer (score 1):

Note that the user can suppress `title` attribute tooltips in Firefox by setting the advanced configuration parameter `browser.chrome.toolbar_tips` to `false`.

Comment: But then you get no tooltips at all, which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

This [jQuery tooltip](http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery) script will take the contents of the title and display them in a tooltip (including HTML formatting). Although, it doesn't fix the IE bug of showing the alt text, you could add some script to clear the alt attribute after the page is loaded; but as stated before, this is a bad idea as it will not allow document readers to work as designed.

Comment: i don't want to remove alt text from source. i want to use title text as a tooltip in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer was helpful but the reason the jQuery didn't work is because `this` needs to be the object of a jQuery selector like so:

`jQuery("img").each( function(){ jQuery(this).attr("title",jQuery(this).attr("alt")  ) });`

It was also missing the `)` to close out the `.each()` function.